# jQuery equivalent to CoffeeScript example given

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

How can I write this CoffeeScript in jQuery?  What am I doing wrong?

```
$ ->
    $('.shop .item > img').click ->
        $(this).parent().find(':submit').click()
```

This is my attempt to convert the CoffeeScript to jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".shop .item > img").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(":submit").click()
    });
});
```

Comment: Check the console for error messages: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } `. `}};` should be `});`.

Comment: The title for this question is incredibly vague and misleading. It implies that you're looking for a version of coffee script that is easier to use and browser independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realise coffeescript compiles to javascript right? 
You can try it yourself at [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%24%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%24%28%27.shop%20.item%20%3E%20img%27%29.click%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28this%29.parent%28%29.find%28%27%3asubmit%27%29.click%28%29) but here is the output:

```
$(function() {
  return $('.shop .item > img').click(function() {
    return $(this).parent().find(':submit').click();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes I understand that it compiles the same, but I wanted to understand the syntax better.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a typo in the last line..

Misplaced the braces..

```
    });
)};
```

Supposed to be

```
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered typo. Change last `)}` with `})`.